# Looking for papers/studies on TDD effectivness

Tags: tdd

I'm looking for research papers or studies made on Unit Testing and TDD effectiveness.

Points of interest:

- Does TDD reduce Development time?
- Does overall development cost reduced as well?
- Is the result product more stable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Microsoft Research: **Realizing quality improvement through test driven
development: results and experiences of four industrial
teams**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/ese/nagappan_tdd.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

[StudiesOfTestDrivenDevelopment](http://biblio.gdinwiddie.com/biblio/StudiesOfTestDrivenDevelopment) has a summary and more links.

Answer (score 5):

An article on infoQ: [Empirical Studies Show Test Driven Development Improves Quality](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/TDD-Improves-Quality).

And a link to the [Realizing quality improvement through TDD study](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/esm/nagappan_tdd.pdf).

"TDD seems to be applicable in various domains and can significantly reduce the defect density of developed software without significant productivity reduction of the development team." The study compared 4 projects, at Microsoft and IBM that used TDD with similar projects that did not use TDD.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.eclipsecon.org/summiteurope2007/presentations/ESE2007_TDD-case_study.pdf

http://www.thycotic.com/casestudy4.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at papers by Nancy Van Schooenderwoert (et al) at [www.agilerules.com](http://www.agilerules.com/). In particular "Embedded Agile Project by the Numbers With Newbies"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/test-driven-development-presentation has a nice presentation explaining TDD though it is geared to Zend and PHP.

http://biblio.gdinwiddie.com/biblio/StudiesOfTestDrivenDevelopment has a number of relevant links